# Performing a loop in SQL Server query

Tags: python, loops

Good morning, what do I have to change in this code to execute a loop that will execute the query as many times as number of rows in the csv file and will increase the 'i' index and with each execution?

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aMFG.png)

Comment: Please post as a text not screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume *filecontent* is a list. In this case, try to replace your `while` loop with that:

```
for i in range(len(filecontent)):
    sql = ...
```

Please make sure to remove `i=i+1` line from the end of your loop.

Comment: Proszę, panu :)